# update a temp table via join or update

Tags: sql, performance

Had an interesting scenario play out today and wondered if some indexing gurus could shed any light...

A query involved a temp table with a dummy value in columnA ..

ColumnA was then Updated via your typical UPDATE statement.

In testing
a developer then created a second temp table ( without columnA), added an index on the joins predicates.. then  via a join to the table needed to Update columnA created a second temp table with the ColumnA coming via join.

It was faster than the UPDATE .. in your opinion is this simply the NONE CLUSTERED INDEX Speeding the join up.. and if not, why is UPDATE on a temp table slower than left joining and grabbing needed values..? My take on it is the index is the only reason it was faster and they should apply the index and roll with the UPDATE AS ORIGINAL

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (This is a product specific issue.)

Comment: If you look at the EXPLAIN PLAN for the queries it will show you what each one is doing. If it’s not clear to you what the EXPLAINs are showing then post them to your question and someone should be able to help

Comment: Your question iis not answerable without details of which RDBMS you're using, the table schema and the actual execution / explain plans

Comment: SQL Server 2008 ... I'm gonna replicate some examples elsewhere in the same dB.. and see why via execution plans